# Can I beat Agahnim without the Master Sword?

Tags: zelda-link-to-the-past, zelda-a-link-to-the-past-randomizer

So I've gotten 2 of 3 pendants in my Link to the Past: Randomized run, but I don't have the Master Sword, because I can't find the bow to get to the Eastern Palace boss. I am able to skip the barrier with the cape, but can I beat Agahnim without the Master Sword?

UPDATE: Defeated Agahnim with normal sword before getting moon pearl. Now to trial-and-error my way to finding the Moon Pearl in the Light World...mnugh...

Comment: follow-up for down here: can I get the bow in the randomized castle? :P

Comment: As far as I know, the Randomizer always puts the Moon Pearl and Mirror in the light world.  As such, it's possible to use that and the other items you get to warp to certain parts of the Dark World even without beating Agahnim.

Comment: Hmm, the "randomized" version basically makes the game play completely different, so be careful of answering the game with your "knowledge".  The Randomized version was released June 2016.

Comment: @ToTheMax You can get the bow, or any key items, in **any** chest, anywhere.  Go explorer everything.

Comment: To the oblivious, this makes no sense whatsoever, yet it still qualifies as a perfectly legitimate question. Love it.

Comment: @Nelson You've added that tag twice now, but I have an issue with its formatting. Can you consider something like *zelda-lttp-randomizer* instead? I don't like that there's no delimiter before *randomizer*.

Comment: I tried to follow the "official" name because I have a 25 character limit.  I'm not sure what else to do really.  Googling "lttp-randomizer" DOES return the Github page on the first hit, so that's a viable alternative.  I didn't see the tag being rejected in my edits due to the OP rolling back my changes.

Comment: In case anyone wants to know, the cape can also be used to bypass the electricity in front of the castle tower.  As for the randomizer, it moved to a [web page](http://vt.alttp.run/) at some point.

Comment: @Powerlord - I believe (for the most recent version, at least) that the Moon Pearl can be in Checkerboard Cave near the Desert Palace, though you'd still need the Mirror to access that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The game *should* have coding to prevent you from getting stuck, since the loot tables are tuned to make sure you can progress.

However, "progress" does not necessarily mean you beat that specific objective.  It may mean beating things in a completely different order, and going to completely random places to open more chests for loot.

The simply way to think about it is your key items **will** be somewhere.  You just need to find it.  It can be in all those random "useless" chests you never open, so you'll just need to exhaustively search everywhere for that next drop.

Note:  For those that didn't check, A Link to the Past: Randomizer is a new version of this game with the loot randomized.  It was released June 2016.

https://dessyreqt.github.io/alttprandomizer/

Answer (score 11):

You can reflect his Energy attacks using the Bug-Catching Net that you get from the sick boy in Kakariko village in the non-randomized game.

Comment: Don't have that, either-thanks, though

Comment: What's the randomized game?

Comment: I'll have to down vote this answer because it's just not correct.  This may be a valid answer for the normal game, but it's not valid for the Randomized version.  I think the upvotes are coming from people who did not even do research on the new version of the game.

Comment: Actually, the answer is still valid. You can kill Aganihm with the net, randomization or not if you don't have a sword. Where to find the net and is it randomized is a different thing.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your direct scenario - the Fighter's Sword will still reflect magic back at Agahnim. While the story implies that the Master Sword is required, any sword (or, as noted, Bug Catching Net) will reflect his magic fine.

---

To go more indepth, base Hyrule Tower clearing (Aga1 for short) "requires" the following items to clear. If you don't have these items, then you can safely assume that either you don't need to clear Aga1, or at least don't need to clear it *yet*. Hopefully not ever.

- **Lantern** - There are dark rooms, and basic randomizer logic will always place the Lantern in a way that can be reached without ever setting foot in a dark room. While dark room navigation is possible without it, it's a pain if you're not seasoned into it and again, generally unnecessary.
- **A sword** - Agahnim goes behind a curtain. You need something to cut down that curtain, so even though there's a whole lot of fancy about "You can use bug net to reflect magic!", you'll always have a sword in the first place because of that blasted curtain.
- Either the **Master Sword** (or better) or **Magic Cape**. This is to get past the zappy dude at the entrance.

Usually, it is expected that one has the **Moon Pearl** to do this, because there's really not much to do post-Aga1 without it. The vast majority of any seed what requires Aga1 will generally give you the Moon Pearl early on. But if it doesn't, but you have the other componenets... there's only two items you can possibly get out of this without the Moon Pearl - the Pyramid's outdoors item can be retrieved immediately even as a bunny, and the Lumberjack Tree is accessible if you also have the **Pegasus Boots**.

If you're playing on Swordless logic, then the curtains will be cut. You'll still need the Lantern. You may alternatively have the **Hammer** instead of the Cape to bypass the front door, as it will break the spell just like the Master Sword can. Also you will actually need the **Bug Catching Net** to reflect magic.